# How can I simplify these statements in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am writing a Python program but I am using list comprehensions and other statements which help to condense the code. However, I would like to write these statements in a more elaborative, easy to read statements. I am a very new programmer and would like to teach myself Python starting from a ground level.

Here are the two statements

```
line = [prizeWinnings(money,prices) for money in line]

with open('money.txt') as money, open("prices.txt","r") as winnings:
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Seems fine to me. If you want feedback on working code, though, I'd recommend posting this on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: It is working, I just wanted to know how can I write these 2 statements in another way.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to simplify the code, the first list comprehension can be written as (given you said you wanted to write them in an easy to read way):

```
result = list()
for money in line:
    result.append(prizeWinnings(money,prices))

print result # or whatever you'd like to do with it...
```

The second way is actually a preferred way of writing/reading data from a file b/c `with` statements manage file handling exceptions pretty well, so you wont have corrupt file handles should things go wrong while reading/writing to a file